# How to convert an MultiValueMap<String,String> to Map<String, List<Long>> with Stream?

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, java-stream

Below code snippet accepts multiValue map and converts to Map. Now I want the map to return Map having value List using streams.

```
  public static Map<String, String> decodeMap(MultiValueMap<String, String> multi) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(multi)) {
      return Map.of();
    }
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(multi.entrySet().size());
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : multi.entrySet()) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
          sb.append(',');
        }
        sb.append(s);
      }
      map.put(entry.getKey(), sb.toString());
    }
    return map;
  }
```

This is what i tried but dint work:

```
  Map<String, List<Long>> map = multi.entrySet().stream()
      .filter(f -> multi.containsKey("employee"))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry ::getKey,Collectors.mapping(e -> Long.parseLong(e.getValue()), Collectors.toList())));
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `e.getValue()` is string but you want to store in collection of Integer, how do you define `List<Long>` of map ? Maybe you should use `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: I want to convert the string values to long. List<Long> emp= new Arraylist<>(); How can i store it in collection of integer using java 8?

Comment: i get this error after using long.parseLong " Cannot resolve method 'getValue' in 'Object'"

Comment: Aside - `.filter(f -> multi.containsKey("employee"))` doesn't relate to any line in the imperative approach you've shared and the expected type has changed as well from `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, List<Long>>`

Comment: Add an example input and ouput in your post to make it clear what you want.

Comment: There is no `parseLong` in the code you have posted. You should post what you have tried along with the error description.

Comment: @holger the parse long comment was in correspondence to one some comment. As i wanted Map to have list<Long> parsing it dint work.

Comment: @Naman multivalue map contains employee so i just had to filter it based on it.

Comment: The code as posted in the question tries to assign the result to a `Map<String, List<Long>>` while not having any attempt of converting the `String` to a `Long`. Of course, it doesn’t pass the compiler and needs to be fixed. If you keep the question as-is, that will be the answer. That would be unhelpful, since you posted in a comment that you already tried to insert a `parseLong` call and got an error, so you should do yourself a favor and change the question to show precisely what you tried and which error you got.

Comment: @Holger added the exact way i tried it out! could you please open the question?

Comment: You should also include the error message instead of just saying "it didn't work". Anyway, I can only *vote* to reopen; it will be reopened if enough people vote for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert `MultiValueMap<String, String>` to `Map<String, List<Long>>`, assuming all `MultiValueMap` value are number string.

```
Map<String, List<Long>> map =
    multi.entrySet().stream()
   .filter(f -> multi.containsKey("employee"))
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: This  worked for me.  thanks for your inputs Eklavya!                                    
 multi.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(
                e -> e.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("employee"))
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList())));

Answer (score 3):

The solution to  convert the method into Stream API is fairly simple and can be done through one collector:

```
Map<String, String> map = multi.entrySet().stream() // from Map<String, List<String>>
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(                      // Collected to Map<String, String>
            Entry::getKey,                          // ... the key remains the same
            e -> String.join(",", e.getValue())));  // ... the values are joined to String
```

The method [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) is able to convert a collection of Strings to a single String with particular Strings joined with a defined delimiter.

---

Moreover, the `Map<String, String>` in the first snippet is not compatible with your try at the second one `Map<String, List<Long>>`.

Comment: But i am looking for converting MultiValueMap <String,String> to Map<String,List<Long>> how can i do that?

Comment: Provide sample input and output. How do you want to get List<Long> from String? What you say is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Map<String, List<Long>> map = multi.entrySet().stream()
      .filter(f -> multi.containsKey("employee"))
      .flatMap(e->e.getValue().stream()
      .map(v->new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), v)))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry ::getKey,Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: well still i am getting "Cannot resolve method 'getValue' in 'Object'" error.